# BackgroundWorker open new window and update it

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a `WPF` utility tool that has a lot of processing to do. The processing is done from `MainWindow.xaml` which utilizes a `BackgroundWorker` to execute. What I want to do is open a new separate window called `Logger.xaml` and update a `TextBox` found on the `Logger.xaml` window on the progress of `MainWindow's` execution. The purpose of this is so that a user can continue to select more processing to do from `MainWindow.xaml` while still getting progress updates of ongoing work. So in layman's terms: 1 `MainWindow` to multiple `Logger` windows. Here is what I have so far.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
       bw = new BackgroundWorker();
       bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
       bw.DoWork += (a, b) => WorkerMethod(x, y); //WorkerMethod does all the heavy lifting
       bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void WorkerMethod(string x, string y)
{
       /***some work 1 code***/
       //Somehow open `Logger.xaml` and update its textbox that some work 1 finished.

       /***some work 2 code***/
       //Update its textbox that Work 2 finished.

       etc...
}
```

Should I use `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` somehow to open up a new `Logger` window on another thread and update the `TextBox` in that window? What is the best way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged somehow to open up a new
>   Logger window on another thread and update the TextBox in that window?

Yes, `BackgroundWorker` raises [`ProgressChanged` events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) on the current `SynchronizationContext` of the thread that called `RunWorkerAsync`()..

To receive notifications of progress updates, handle the ProgressChanged event. To receive a notification when the operation is completed, handle the RunWorkerCompleted event.

> What is the best way to achieve the desired effect?

If you want to use a BackgroundWorker, probably this is the best.